# Zfs: how to remove a volume?

Tags: zfs

I've been looking around for this for a while but I can't tell if I am missing something here because this seems a bit basic.

In zfs:

```
sudo zfs create -V 5mb new-pool/zfsvol1
```

When I do "zfs list" I can see I have a lot of zfs volumes clogging up my pool. I want to remove these. I don't understand how? Sorry if this is a very simple question.

Comment: What does this have to do with docker? Is it not just purely a zfs question?

Comment: Sorry yeah I guess it's purely zfs, I was just sharing some perspective of where I was coming from

Comment: ...btw, note that Stack Overflow is only for questions about *writing code*. Questions about using UNIX tools generally belong on [unix.se], or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) (when the tools are suitable for end-users to use), or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) (when those tools are aimed at professional sysadmins rather than individual users).

Comment: Gotcha. Point of tagging is to attract people who are knowledgeable about the question. Docker knowledge doesn't help someone answer this question.

Comment: Ohh got it, thank you, I'll post there next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As covered in the `zfs` man page, `zfs destroy my-vol` removes a volume.